# How to compare name of link with URL of link (with Selenium webdriver in C#)

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to automate the testing of a Sharepoint site, to see if the links are leading to the right URL. Right now I am stuck on how to do the comparison.

I have located the links and put them in a list. I am new to Selenium so I have been trying everything I could think of/Google in the if-statement.

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='skills-table']"));

IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));



            String[] rowTD = new String[tableRow.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement element in tableRow)
            {

                rowTD[i++] = element.Text;


                if (element.Text.Equals   ) // Some kind of comparison

                {


                }
            }
```

Basically, I could just use some ideas on how to move on from this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think your `tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));` expression will return you all the nested links in the table, personally I would rather go for a [relative XPath locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//a"));
   ```
2. If you want to get URL of the link you need to extract [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) via [IWebElement.GetAttribute()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) function

   ```
   var URL = element.GetAttribute("href");
   ```

Comment: Hello, I've added some improvements above if you would like to comment on it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer. I might have figured it out, and could use some comments on the solution. Is Assert.ReferenceEquals solving my problem? The test passes atleast

```
        IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='skills-table']"));
        IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//a"));

        String[] rowTD = new String[tableRow.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (IWebElement element in tableRow)
        {

            rowTD[i++] = element.Text;
            var URL = element.GetAttribute("href");

            Assert.ReferenceEquals(element.Text, URL);
         }
```